# Is there a way to remove node titles?

Tags: 7, nodes

When I make a node such as a basic page I have to give it a Title by default. However, the Title also appears on the page when I am viewing it, but I do not want every node I have to come with a title tacked unto it.  For example, on some of my nodes, they are linked to the navigation bar, so it looks funny to see the same name twice when visiting the page.

Is there a way to remove the Title being represented on the page?

Comment: This for D7 or D8 ?

Comment: Sorry about that, this is for D7.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at the [Exclude Node Title](https://www.drupal.org/project/exclude_node_title) module.

> This module handles a very simple functionality, decide whatever to exclude a node title from full node page or node teasers.
>   It provides a checkbox on node-edit pages for easier exclusion, or you can use the admin page to manually enter a list of node id's to exclude title.
>   Also provides the option to hide all titles of a certain Content type.

Comment: Strange. I added the module and enabled it, but the check-box to hide the title is not present in my edit node overlay.

Comment: You have to go to the settings and setup the behavior of each content type. You can chose between "all nodes" and "user defined nodes". If you want a select option on each node, you have to chose the latter.